# BF 494 Transistor - conflict in pinout

Tags: transistors

It might sound stupid but I'm in a real doubt since many datasheets disagree regarding the  BF494 transistor pinout.

1- http://www.datasheetdir.com/CDIL-BF494+RF-Transistors

2- http://www.electronica-pt.com/db/componentes.php?ref=BF494..495

3- http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/philips/BF494B.pdf

I soldered erroneously because of this confusion and i'm now waiting some insight to sold again.

Comment: It's entirely possible that several different manufacturers have produced transistors labeled "BF494", with different pin-outs. I think you may just have to test each lot of transistors. Alternatively, figure out who specifically manufactured the devices you have, and get *their* datasheet. It should be correct (hopefully).

Comment: lots of DMM have EBC, BEC, ETc. transistor checkers on them use one of those to get the values absolutely.  OR if you don't have that, use the diode checker, there be junctions in there!

Comment: The famous TO-92 package, where the same transistor did indeed nave several different pinouts. Sometimes a suffix like -L distinguished between them... rawbrawb's idea will let you identify the base. Then consult the datasheets for collector and emitter...

Comment: I don't trust your 2nd link, it isn't an original datasheet and it looks like someone manually selected a standard figure that often (but not always) goes with this package. The other two datasheets are identical in pinning. The Philips datasheet shows the transistor from the bottom (the side where the pins come out of the package). It doesn't hurt to double check with a diode check.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheets are perfectly fine.
First link has no datasheet at all, its just a list of some possible substitutes with strange information from strange sources.
Second and third links shows the same pinout: 1-Base 2-Em 3-Col.